# Reload data in ViewController after asynchronous method finished

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, reloaddata

I have a `UIViewController` with an `UIImageView` display an initial image.

I use asynchronous to download another image --> store in Directory, then I change the `UIImageView` to my new downloaded image.

Therefore, I want the `UIViewController` refresh to process new data. Is there any method in `UIViewController` similar to `reloaddata()` in `TableViewController`?

PS: I don't want delete ImageView and add new Subview in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I think I would need more information to fully answer the question, but if you change the .image property of the UIImageView, then the image should change. It's possible that you might have to do that on the main queue for it to work properly because UI changes have to be done in the main queue.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    //Change UIImageView.image property here
}
```